# Google Sheets Script - How to automate "if checkbox == true, then copy row in another sheet" in the same spreadsheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

Good day guys,

First of all, the spreadsheet is named `Daily File Distribution`.

So the issue here is:
If a checkbox in `'Daily!H2:H100'` is `TRUE`, then the contents from Columns `'Daily!A2:F100'` are to be copied to `'Record'` last row. Then clear the contents from `'Daily!A2:F100'` (as deleting rows mess up the conditional formatting). And then change the checkboxes from `'Daily!G2:H2'` to be `FALSE`.

I got this from a macro recorded (which is only for `Daily!A2:F2`):

```
function UntitledMacro() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:F2').activate();
  spreadsheet.setCurrentCell(spreadsheet.getRange('F2'));
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Record'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A134').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Daily'), true);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
  spreadsheet.getRange('H2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('FALSE');
};
```

Advance thanks!

Comment: Share an example spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Daily');
  var sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Record');
  var rg1=sh1.getRange(2,1,99,6);
  var rg2=sh1.getRange(2,7,99,2);
  var vA1=rg1.getValues();
  var vA2=rg2.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA1.length;i++) {
    if(vA2[i][1]) {
      sh2.appendRow(vA1[i])
      sh1.getRange(i+2,1,1,vA1[i].length).clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
      vA2[i][0]=false;
      vA2[i][1]=false;
    }
  }
  rg2.setValues(vA2);
}
```

Comment: After looking at your file, I think may be you might want to reread your question carefully because you said you want to check if column H is true and if it is then copy to record and clear data.  But your page makes me think that I should have checked column G.

Comment: It is column H. 'G' is for when someone finishes typing their report, and 'H' for when that someone gets the edited report. So it's good!